# Latitude and Longitude of IP Addresses using R

Tags: r, ip-address, latitude-longitude

I have a huge list of IP addresses. Is there a way using R to get the corresponding latitude and the longitude of these addresses?

Thank you.

Ravi

Answer (score 10):

This is a valuable commercial process, so any online API lookups will be either a) expensive, or b) slow.

Your best option may be to download the MaxMind City IP data base:

http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite

and get GeoLite City - the CSV version of this contains two files, one maps IP address blocks to location IDs, and the other maps locationIDs to towns and lat-long coordinates. e.g.:

```
startIpNum,endIpNum,locId
"16777216","16777471","17"
"16777472","16777727","104084"
"16777728","16778239","49"
```

which tell you that IPs in the second block range are in:

```
104084,"CN","07","Fuzhou","",26.0614,119.3061,,
```

So all you need to do is write some R code to read in those databases, encode the dotted IP addresses you have into the form used here (32 bit integer, probably) and do a couple of lookups. You might get best performance by using data.table, or sticking it all in an SQL database, or writing some C code with their C API to the binary versions of the files and linking it with R via Rcpp or other magic.

OMG someone already did this!!

http://devblog.icans-gmbh.com/using-the-maxmind-geoip-api-with-r/

and OMG2!! someone made it into a package:

http://www.rforge.net/GeoIP/files/

note that these last two solutions use a local copy of the database rather than doing queries of the web page and so won't be throttled.

I've just got the GeoIP package working very simply and it is fast. You may want to update the DB file it comes with, or it might be up to date enough. The package requires no other download to work.

Comment: This GeoIP package doesn't work anymore... shows a message that the account has been suspended... I am guessing the author had an account with the DB when it was written... you any solutions for current times?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at **http://ipinfodb.com/** or **http://freegeoip.net/**

They offer APIs to get the lat/long from an IP address. (not R-specific, though)

Comment: Currently, I am only looking for R based solutions. If R doesn't work out, I will definitely give this a try.

Comment: freegeoip.net works for any language that can make HTTP GET requests. I'm pretty sure it can be achieved in R.

Answer (score 4):

The [geoPlot package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geoPlot/) has a  function `ipListLookup`

Comment: Just tried the ipListLookup with the example given in the documentation. This function appears to be very slow. A data frame with 5 IP addresses took me close to 2 minutes. I have close to 200K IP addresses for which I need the latitude and longitude and this function would turn out to be very time consuming. Is there a more efficient way to get the latitude and longitude?

Comment: The help for geoIP tells you it is querying ipinfodb.com's API. If you go look at their docs they say 'queries that are at a rate faster than 2 per second will be put in "queue"'. You could loop your R queries with a pause but it will still take over a day.